# Pandas aggregating values of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example of my DataFrame

```
  user    workflow    device     location  date 
  A         top         Mac      SF        1/1/19
  B         left        Win      SA        1/1/19
  A         right       Mac      SF        1/5/19
  C         left        iphone   LA        1/7/19
  D         left        pixel    BO        1/20/19
  C         bottom      iphone   LA        1/21/19
```

I want to transform the DF to look like this:

```
 User top bottom left right Mac Win iphone pixel SF  SA   LA  BO
 A     1   0     0      1   1   0     0     0     2   0   0    0
 B     0   0     1      0   0   1     0     0     0   1   0    0
 C     0   1     1      0   0   0     2     0     0   0   2    0
 D     0   0     1      0   0   0     0     1     0   0   0    1
```

How would one do that using Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.get_dummies` after `stack`

```
s=df.set_index('user').stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
s  
      BO  LA  Mac  SA  SF  Win  bottom  iphone  left  pixel  right  top
user                                                                   
A      0   0    2   0   2    0       0       0     0      0      1    1
B      0   0    0   1   0    1       0       0     1      0      0    0
C      0   2    0   0   0    0       1       2     1      0      0    0
D      1   0    0   0   0    0       0       0     1      1      0    0
```

Comment: what if I had other columns I am not using in the DataFrame. How would I still output the same result?

Comment: @user5844628 I am not get the , what you mean other columns but not in the data frame ?

Comment: please see updated DateFrame. I add a `date` column but I do not desire to use that in my transformed counts

Comment: @user5844628 I think I get you , `df.drop('date',1).set_index('user').stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)`

Comment: Thanks! What if you had 100+ columns you are not using. Is there an easier way to drop those without specifically calling the column names out as you are doing here?

Comment: @user5844628 select the column you need , like `df[['user','workflow','device','     location']].set_index('user').stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)`

Comment: @user5844628 is this what you need ?

Comment: I just ran that on my dataset of 1 million rows but got an `MemoryError` not sure why. Can `str.get_dummies().sum(level=0) ` handle large data sets?

Comment: @user5844628 I do not think this will handle more than 1 million row, you may need split your df into subset , then running above , then `concat` back

Comment: @user5844628 you may look at dask :-) there is no much I can help:-( with out the real data

Comment: @user5844628 also I recommend you open a new question about the pivot , rather than modify the original ones (also you did not provided the expected output and the `event.count` columns )

Comment: Thanks @Wen-Ben, I took the pivot part out from the question. Your method works for smaller datasets.  I just need a way to do this to handle a larger (1million +) dataset.